# "Полная версия сайта" на мобильном

Tags: media-queries, viewport

Сверстал сайт. Загрузил на фтп. В десктоп браузере при изменении ширины и высоты все адаптивится, в инспекторе кода тоже, на мобильных устройствах и планшетах отображаются правильные размеры и разрешения. Но если в мобильном браузере (chrome и safari пробовал) нажать "показать полную версию сайта" - ничего не меняется. Страница перезагружается и вновь показывает тот же мобильный вариант странички.
На странице есть viewport и media queries.
На фтп лежит чистая верстка и пару js скриптов.
В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD** вопрос можно поставить и так: как отловить нажатие на кнопку "показать полную версию в браузере", как с ней обращаться и как под неё верстать. Статей пока на эту тему найти не могу, роюсь на бурж источниках в том числе.
Могу предположить что кнопка "показать полную версию сайта" меняет viewport на десктопный, но это догадки.

Comment: ссылка ессть на сайт ?

Comment: На тот который делаю сейчас не могу скинуть, он для работы. Вот например нашел один из старых сайтов, в котором верстал маленький кусок, он тоже не загружает полную версию. http://skyfitclub.com.ua потыкал я на разные сайты, свои и чужие, многие не переходят на полную версию. Вопрос скорее в том, как работает кнопка перехода в браузере и как отловить её нажатие.

Comment: Кнопки, подобные «Показать полную версию», всего лишь меняют юзерагент с мобильного на десктопный. Иногда и viewport меняется, но вроде не у всех

Comment: @andreymal , почему некоторые адаптивные сайты не переходят на десктоп версию и как можно это исправить? Почему не меняется useragent?

Comment: @neku894 как вы проверяете, что не меняется useragent?

Comment: @andreymal, я не проверял, я предположил это исходя из того что сайт не меняет свой внешний вид. Судя по всему это не так, вот что я нашел: https://codereview.chromium.org/1785953002 здесь есть упоминание о том, что хром устанавливает разрешение 980px. Проверил. С устройств android действительно берется разрешение между 768 и 992 (до этого момента тестил только на iphone5). А вот на ios как не работало ничего, так и не работает. Остается мобильная версия сайта.

Comment: @neku894 ну значит ios не меняет viewport, а сайт игнорирует useragent ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯